# json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type map[string]interface {}

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, unmarshalling

`terraform apply` throws error:

```
Error: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type map[string]interface {}

  on main.tf line 145, in data "aws_lambda_invocation" "update-user-pool-invocation":
 145: data "aws_lambda_invocation" "update-user-pool-invocation" {
```

The code, according to the [doc](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/lambda_invocation.html):

```
data "aws_lambda_invocation" "update-user-pool-invocation" { # line 145 is this one
  function_name = module.update-user-pool.function_name
  input = <<JSON
{
  "Name": "Invocation"
}
JSON
}
```

What number it cannot unmarshal? There are no numbers. I tried:

- replace input section with `input = {}` because I don't really need it
- write input as `input = "{ \"Name\": \"Invocation\" }"`
- copy&paste input from the doc

How to fix it?

Comment: That code is fine (run it as a stand alone thing to see for yourself) so it must be something else in your code before that that is upsetting the parser.

Comment: From peeking at the implementation of `aws_lambda_invocation` in https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/aws/data_source_aws_lambda_invocation.go , it seems likely that this error is happening trying to decode the function _result_ rather than the input you are providing, since it seems to just send your input JSON verbatim to the server as a string.